# Mysql Command line fires REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES but not REVOKE SELECT

Tags: mysql, database, command-line, mysql-5.5

I am running Queries from command line, I have to revoke only select option from particular database tables of an user, so i used below statement for this.

`REVOKE SELECT ON test_db.* FROM 'testuser'@'localhost';`

It shows error `1141: There is no such grant defined for user 'testuser' on host 'localhost'`

But Runs Below Statement:

`REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES , GRANT OPTION FROM 'testuser'@'localhost';`

I am running this queries from `root` user and i did not get any idea because `root` and `testuser` have all privileges, i am using mysql 5.5.

Comment: This means user doesn't have 

    SELECT for test_db.* defined. 

Refer http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57377/revoking-mysql-table-level-privileges